# PHP foreach generated array name select

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

im trying to set a arrayname with a generated id.

```
$storeIdx = $_POST['storeID'];

$generatedArrayName = '$itemStore'.$storeIdx;

$itemStore1 = array($itemStore1_1,$itemStore1_2);
$itemStore1_1 = 'a';
$itemStore1_2 = 'b';

$itemStore2 = array($itemStore2_1,$itemStore2_2);
$itemStore2_1 = 'c';
$itemStore2_2 = 'd';

foreach($generatedArrayName as $itemVar){
//code here
}
```

But im getting a error which looks like : Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in url on line 27

Line27:

```
foreach($generatedArrayName as $itemVar){
```

How could i set the first foreach parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foreach()` need an `array()` but you provided a `string`.
`$generatedArrayName` not an `array()` is a `string`